# Chrome/Firefox opened in Slack, PyCharm etc. are in the wrong sidebar groups

Tags: 20.04, firefox, google-chrome

Usually, when I open Chrome/Firefox from Slack or PyCharm/IntellijIdea, it shows up in the sidebar group of the app that it was opened from. Then, other instances are being added to the group too.

It's very annoying and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Is there a universal solution for this?